# Instantiate object with parameters in a different file that I have created it (C++)

Tags: c++

I have two classes in C++ and I am using one object inside another. Hence, I have to instantiate one. I am only able to instantiate it as a pointer (with *), but not like a normal instantiation `MyObj b;` on the header and `b = new MyObj(parameters);` on the cpp file. I know that if I created the object on the same file I could use `MyObj b(param);` and I will not create a pointer. But if I split the creating and the instantiation into different files I cannot do.
How should I do this?
ps: I must use dynamic parameters on the constructor as well.
thanks

GPS.h file

```
class GPS : public ISensor {
    public:
        SkinnyBuffer *buffer;
        // SkinnyBuffer buffer; // IF I create my object like this
        GPS();
        GPS(PRIVILEGES replay, std::string file = "GPS");
        ~GPS();
}
```

GPS.cpp file

```
GPS::GPS() : ISensor() {
    GPS(PRIVILEGES::NO_ACCESS);
}
GPS::GPS(PRIVILEGES record, std::string file) : ISensor(record, file) {
    std::size_t size = 5 * sizeof(double);
    buffer = new SkinnyBuffer(size);

    // buffer = new SkinnyBuffer(size);  // WHY CAN I NOT DO THIS?
    // buffer(size); // WHY CAN I NOT DO THIS?
    ............
}
GPS::~GPS() {
    .............
}
```

Comment: Have you included the file defining the `SkinnyBuffer` class in your `GPS.cpp` source file?

Comment: By the way, unless you start using smart pointers (like e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) for your `buffer` member, you need to initialize it in the default constructor as well. I also recommend you do the initialization as part of the constructor initializer list as well.

Comment: yes. `#include "utils/SkinnyBuffer.h"` is included on the header and I tested on the GPS.cpp and does not make difference.

Comment: Then you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, together with the full and complete error output you get. Otherwise we can't help you more.

Comment: sorry, I did test `buffer = SkinnyBuffer(size);` and now worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours SkinnyBuffer probably have not default constructor, so you should initialize it in constructor's initializer list:

```
// GPS.h file
class GPS : public ISensor
{
public:
    SkinnyBuffer buffer;
    GPS();
    GPS(PRIVILEGES replay, std::string file = "GPS");
    ~GPS();
}

// GPS.cpp file
//
GPS::GPS() : ISensor(), buffer(5 * sizeof(double)) // initialize buffer
{
    GPS(PRIVILEGES::NO_ACCESS);
}

GPS::GPS(PRIVILEGES record, std::string file) : ISensor(record, file),
    buffer(5 * sizeof(double)) // initialize buffer
{

}

GPS::~GPS()
{
    //.............
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it seemed to me that it uses a form with a pointer, because it cannot correctly initialize variable;
He asked: "// SkinnyBuffer buffer; // IF I create my object like this"...

Comment: Good point. It's still speculation though since we don't know the errors the OP is getting.